# Is a Brazilian RNE accepted by airlines or is a visa required?

Tags: visas, paperwork, brazil, registration

I am married to a Brazilian citizen and I was recently given an RNE (Registro Nacional de Estrangeiro or National Alien Registration card). Last year, I visited Brazil with a tourist visa and this time I have the RNE.

Will my RNE be accepted to board a flight to Brazil, or will I be asked for a visa. 
I checked with local my Brazilian Consulate and they informed me that a visa is not required. Still, I want to confirm the with someone who has already travelled with just the RNE.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can enter Brazil with the RNE and your passport.

Timatic, the system which helps airlines verify passenger documents, states:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with an ID card issued to residents of Brazil if stay abroad does not exceed 2 years.

Timatic provides a list of valid ID cards, one of which is:

> Cedula de Identidade de Estrangerio [sic]

You will notice that your RNE has this phrase printed on it (though spelled correctly).

Comment: The spelling error is intentional. This is what ["sic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) means. It is not to be corrected here unless it has been corrected in Timatic.

Comment: Wow, it's still misspelled in Timatic. As of today all of the information here remains identical.